# Change data before it is displayed, on click of dropdownlist in kendo grid

Tags: javascript, kendo-grid

Is there a way to change the data before it is displayed in a dropdown AS you click to edit the field?

Using a simpler solution and trying to use dataBinding, which is supposed to fire before the data is bound (and available on dropDownList as well), it doesn't appear to be able to change the data before the data runs. Or at least doesn't update it.

The deep dive into the problem is that I want to run a for loop around the array of data, and perform some operations on it, based on the rest of the data in the row.

The simpler idea, is that I want to edit the data before it is displayed, on click of the kendo grid.

https://dojo.telerik.com/UROwaWoN

```
var mydata = [
    { name: "Jane Doe", age: 30 },
    { name: "John Doe", age: 33 }];
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
  columns: [
    { field: "name" },
    { field: "age" }
  ],
  dataSource: mydata,
  dataBinding: function(e) {
    mydata.push({ name: "Kane Madison", age: 24 });
    console.log("dataBinding");
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was that I have to set the datasource again. I did this by setting the datasource within the "edit" function on the options (before the dropdownlist select event). It looks like this:

```
edit: function(event) {
  // .....
  if (selectedFieldName == "thefieldIwant") {
    let newDataSource = remapDataBased
    let dropdownList = ..... (get dropdownlist from Kendogrid)

    dropdownList.setDataSource(newDataSource);
  }

}
```

I think it's possible there are other solutions to this, but this has been up a few days and nobody has found them yet.